# Meaning of this Assembly Program

Tags: assembly

I am trying to understand this assembly program which supposedly converts a two digit unpacked BCD number to :

1) ASCII equivalent

2) Packed BCD equivalent

```
;Unpacked BCD to ASCII & Packed BCD
.model small
.data
    msg db 10,13,'Two ASCII Digits are ' 
    asci1 db 30h,' and '
    asci2 db 30h, '$'
.code segment 
start:
    mov ax, @data ;Initializing data Segment register 
    mov ds, ax
    mov al, 2 ;1st Unpacked BCD number 
    mov bl, 4 ;2nd Unpacked BCD number
    add asci1, al ;equivalent ascii 
    add asci2, bl
    mov bh, al ;1st Unpacked bcd to bh 
    mov cl, 4 ;to shift lower 4 bits to higher 
    shl bh, cl
    or bh, bl ;Combine to get packed bcd in bh 
    lea dx, msg 

    ;Display All
    mov ah, 9 
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4ch ; exit to operating system. 
    int 21h
end start ; stop the assembler.
```

I particularly do not understand the three lines in data segment specially what do numbers 10,13, 30h mean there.

I also do not understand the code section specially how `msg` gets to combine the the first line with the numbers and the word 'and' between them.

i;e The output of this program is:

```
The ASCII digits are 2 and 4
```

I understand the last section of code which displays and exits to the os.

Please explain why and how this program does what it does.

Comment: The `msg db 10,13` adds a CRLF to the end of the `Two ASCII Digits...` statement.

Comment: You need to look at an ASCII chart. 10 is `LF`, 13 is `CR`, 30h is the character '0'.